# Retrieving logs from log4net table

Tags: c#, sql, log4net

I am using log4net for my c# code to insert log into database using the configuration,

```
<appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
<bufferSize value="100" />
<connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, 
System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
<connectionString value="data source=[database server];
initial catalog=[database name];integrated security=false;
persist security info=True;User ID=[user];Password=[password]" />
<commandText value="INSERT INTO Log ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],
[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, 
@logger, @message, @exception)" />
<parameter>
<parameterName value="@log_date" />
<dbType value="DateTime" />
<layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
</parameter>
<parameter>
<parameterName value="@thread" />
<dbType value="String" />
<size value="255" />
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
  <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
  </layout>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<parameterName value="@log_level" />
<dbType value="String" />
<size value="50" />
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
  <conversionPattern value="%level" />
</layout>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<parameterName value="@logger" />
<dbType value="String" />
<size value="255" />
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
  <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
</layout>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<parameterName value="@message" />
<dbType value="String" />
<size value="4000" />
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
  <conversionPattern value="%message" />
 </layout>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<parameterName value="@exception" />
<dbType value="String" />
<size value="2000" />
<layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
</parameter>
</appender>
```

So i just need to use their inbuilt functions for inserting data to table. Now i need to retrieve data from the log table. Is log4net providing any functions for retrieving data from table? Or the only way to retrive data from this table is writing my own query? Anyone please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it, but a simple Google search got me to http://code.google.com/p/log4net-db-viewer/ and some other results.
It does not look like there is any built in reader for any appender.

Answer (score 1):

Log4net does not give you any tools to read your logs. Its only for making logs and it depends on the appenders to format and save the logs somewhere. There are many projects and samples which can read your logs depending on your appender:

[read log4net logs](http://www.google.nl/#output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=read+log4net+logs&oq=read+log4net+logs&gs_l=hp.3..0i19j0i8i30i19l2.912.5458.0.5670.19.17.1.1.1.1.396.4646.2-1j13.14.0....0...1c.1.21.psy-ab.Sx7YxHO39EU&pbx=1&fp=1&biw=1259&bih=1027&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&cad=b)